# Next-Auth JWT Decryption Failed

Tags: jwt, next.js13, next-auth

I'm trying to get the token in a server component but it prints null. I read that it could be due to the error `JWEDecryptionFailed: decryption operation failed` which is the one I'm getting:

```
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error decryption operation failed {
  message: 'decryption operation failed',
  stack: 'JWEDecryptionFailed: decryption operation failed\n' +
    '    at gcmDecrypt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/runtime/decrypt.js:68:15)\n' +
    '    at decrypt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/runtime/decrypt.js:91:20)\n' + 
    '    at flattenedDecrypt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwe/flattened/decrypt.js:137:52)\n' +
    '    at async compactDecrypt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwe/compact/decrypt.js:20:23)\n' +
    '    at async jwtDecrypt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwt/decrypt.js:10:23)\n' +
    '    at async Object.decode (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/jwt/index.js:44:25)\n' +    
    '    at async Object.session (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/session.js:25:34)\n' +
    '    at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:161:37)\n' +    
    '    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:30)\n' +
    '    at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:85:24)\n' + 
    '    at async C:\\Users\\Rax\\Desktop\\zurii-hr-panel\\node_modules\\next\\dist\\compiled\\next-server\\app-route.runtime.dev.js:1:66877',
  name: 'JWEDecryptionFailed'
}
```

This is my options.ts:

```js
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2h54xz6Ndw&t=1721s

import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import AppleProvider from "next-auth/providers/apple"
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';

import loginService from "@/services/auth";

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
    secret: "123",
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                email: {
                    label: "Email",
                    type: "email",
                    placeholder: "Email"
                },
                password: {
                    label: "Password:",
                    type: "password",
                    placeholder: "Password"
                }
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                // This is where you need to retrieve user data 
                // to verify with credentials
                // Docs: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/credentials
                const email = credentials?.email || "";
                const password = credentials?.password || "";

                let user = await loginService.login(email, password);
                // modify object
                user = {
                    token: user.access_token
                }

                if (user && user.token) {
                    return user;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            return { ...token, ...user };
        },

        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.user = token as any;
            return session;
        },
    },
    pages: {
       signIn: "/login" 
    }
};
```

I don't know what's wrong. But adding the secret didn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Changing this

```
secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET
```

to this

```
secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET
```

worked for me